# Code debugging via list box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bit long code in **btnCall_Click** procedure and I'd like to have code under control - in other words I'd like to know where the code actually is. For this purpose I'm using **list box**. This works fine in win forms concept - when you run the code, you can see the text in list box and you can imagine where the program is. But when I try the same thing in asp.net it'll show the text in list box after program finishes... Is there any solution how can I see program flow in listbox? Thanks a lot for any of your help.

```
protected void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDebug.Items.Add("Loading Libraries...");

    // another code part

    lblDebug.Items.Add("Loading Functions...");

   // another code part
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Number of ways to progress, you can use Ajax/updatepanels to update the UI, or you could go to other methods such as the debug trace or display debug information in a trace/logging file etc.

Answer (score 0):

Of course because your method is running on the server side. When you click on your Call button there is a postback to the server that executes the code and you get the response only when the method is finished.

For debuging long method I simply use the Debug.WriteLine() method.

Comment: I'd like to provide info about debug to user by list box.